# Best way to get the latest Identity when inserting through View

Tags: sql-server

I am using View and View trigger to insert data into multiple tables.
In this case, how can I get the inserted ID of the specific table?
I was using IDENT_CURRENT but it's not recommended.
How can I implement this using SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Answer (score 0):

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope